# EMULADOR ANDROID NAO ESTÁ FUNCIONANDO

Tags: android, emulador

Tentei abrir tanto no terminal quanto na propria plataforma , ambos mostram tela preta

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Acrescenta as config do seu pc...Processador, memória ram...

Comment: É um i5 da 9 gen , 8gb de RAM .. Usava o emulador todo dia tranquilo , o problema começou ontem msm

Comment: Já tentou criar outro device? Se um novo apresentar o mesmo problema, tenta reinstalar o HAXM. Se mesmo assim não funcionar baixa outra versão da api e tenta criar um novo device. Pode ser algum arquivo corrompido.

Comment: Deu certo mano , desinstalei e instalei o HAXM pelo próprio android studio , reiniciei o PC , e voltou a funcionar , muito obrigado !!